# Eclipse - how to create a new project with drag 'n' drop controls capability

Tags: android, sdk

I'm watching a video from Google I/O on a way to create an android app by dragging and dropping elements onto the eclipse window.  Example: if you want a button, you just drag a button onto the screen.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oq05KqjXTvs @ 0:07:25

I've downloaded JDK, Android SDK, and the ADT Plugin, but, I cannot figure out how to get to the place where I can drag 'n' drop controls into my app.  In Eclipse, after configuring the ADT Plugin, I went to `File -> New -> Project -> Android Project`, and I do not see a panel on the left with a list of controls.

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only drag and drop on to layout files (.xml). Now that you have created a new project, you will have automatically created the default main.xml. This will be in the res\layout  folder as shown in the project explorer view. If you click on that you will get two tabs for editing it, one is plain text, the other is the graphical view - this is where you drag widgets to.

Answer (score 1):

The screen that you referred to is what you see when you work with the layout file.  Create a new class and create a layout for it.  Select the layout then you can drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

Havent seen the video , but after you create a project you will have to go to res->layout->click on xml file. The editor for xml file has a tab called graphical Layout. You can drag and drop controls in this editor